# Can i build with Mono in Unity for armv7 and x86 and then in android studio add arm64 to gradle build file?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, gradle

I have problem with il2cpp build in Unity

Build error - OutOfMemoryException.

I build in unity with Mono for armv7 and x86. Export to android studio. And in android studio  i add

```
abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'x86','arm64-v8a','x86_64'
```

i build this. But my build didn't work. It crash after opening.

Error text

```
2019-06-19 17:30:05.743 804-837/? E/ANDR-PERF-RESOURCEQS: Failed to apply optimization [4, 0]
2019-06-19 17:30:05.743 1387-1612/? E/ANDR-PERF-JNI: com_qualcomm_qtiperformance_native_perf_io_prefetch_start
2019-06-19 17:30:05.745 804-837/? E/ANDR-PERF-RESOURCEQS: Failed to apply optimization [4, 0]

    --------- beginning of system
2019-06-19 17:30:05.750 1387-1612/? E/ActivityTrigger: activityStartTrigger: not whiteListedcom.CompanyName.GameName/com.CompanyName.GameName.UnityPlayerActivity/5
2019-06-19 17:30:05.751 1387-1612/? E/ActivityTrigger: activityResumeTrigger: not whiteListedcom.CompanyName.GameName/com.CompanyName.GameName.DeliveryRacing.UnityPlayerActivity/5
2019-06-19 17:30:05.761 1387-7412/? E/ActivityTrigger: activityResumeTrigger: not whiteListedcom.CompanyName.GameName/com.CompanyName.GameName.UnityPlayerActivity/5
2019-06-19 17:30:06.337 18688-18688/com.CompanyName.GameName E/Unity: Unable to find main
2019-06-19 17:30:06.514 18688-18688com.CompanyName.GameName E/zygote64: No implementation found for void com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.nativeRestartActivityIndicator() (tried Java_com_unity3d_player_UnityPlayer_nativeRestartActivityIndicator and Java_com_unity3d_player_UnityPlayer_nativeRestartActivityIndicator__)
2019-06-19 17:30:06.518 18688-18688/com.CompanyName.GameNameg E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.CompanyName.GameName, PID: 18688
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for void com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.nativeRestartActivityIndicator() (tried Java_com_unity3d_player_UnityPlayer_nativeRestartActivityIndicator and Java_com_unity3d_player_UnityPlayer_nativeRestartActivityIndicator__)
        at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.nativeRestartActivityIndicator(Native Method)
        at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.resume(Unknown Source:23)
        at com.CompanyName.GameName.UnityPlayerActivity.onResume(UnityPlayerActivity.java:57)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1356)
        at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:7196)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3602)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3667)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2901)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1616)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:171)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6651)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:824)
2019-06-19 17:30:06.635 1387-1684/? E/ActivityTrigger: activityResumeTrigger: not whiteListedcom.miui.home/com.miui.home.launcher.Launcher/40950894
2019-06-19 17:30:06.997 18207-18207/? E/Launcher: changeViewByFsGestureState,  view=FitSystemWindowView,  alpha=1.0,  scale=1.0
2019-06-19 17:30:06.997 18207-18207/? E/Launcher: changeViewByFsGestureState,  view=ForceTouchLayer,  alpha=1.0,  scale=1.0
2019-06-19 17:30:11.902 1387-1578/? E/AppScanObserverService: Result available, null observers for user: 0
2019-06-19 17:30:13.908 1387-1412/? E/BatteryExternalStatsWorker: no controller energy info supplied for bluetooth
2019-06-19 17:30:13.935 21867-21887/? E/cr3: B|rv| DrawPageTask.work(720,1121)
```

Comment: how much memory does the machine building the app have?

Comment: i use laptop with 4gb RAM

Comment: i try to eneble il2cpp build with only ARMv7.but i still have problem

Comment: @BugFinder this is RAM problem?

Comment: there is no problem with empty project. There are googl ads, googl analytics, facebook ads and facebook analytics in my project. I need all of them

Comment: you are litterally out of memory, I thought 8gb was the recommended minimum